# Adding Event Handler to Constructor method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, addeventlistener

I am trying to make a class that creates a list element while attaching an event listener to it. The following is my code:

```
class listItem {

    constructor(id) {
        this.id = id;       
        this.li = $("<li>");
        this.li.text(this.id);

        // Selector
        this.li.on("click", function() {
            this.li.text("clicked");
        });
    }

    getDom() {
        return this.li;
    }
}
```

I invoke this class using the following:

```
// Creating a new listElement and appending it to the list
var l1 = new listItem(1);
$("ul").append(l1.getDom());
```

However, when I click on the element, I get the following error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined
>
> > at HTMLLIElement. ((index):56)
> >
> > at HTMLLIElement.dispatch (jquery.js:5206)
> >
> > at HTMLLIElement.elemData.handle (jquery.js:5014)

Here is my jsfiddle of the [code](https://jsfiddle.net/7ucxpmr1/3/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `this`'s context.  You're using the `this`'s context of `this.li.on("click", function() {...}` rather than of your class `listItem`.

Store the `this` value into a variable, i.e: `$self`.

```
let $self = this;
```

```js
class listItem {

    constructor(id) {
        this.id = id;       
        this.li = $("<li>");
        this.li.text(this.id);
        
        let $self = this;
        
        this.li.on("click", function() {
            $self.li.text("clicked");
        });
    }

    getDom() {
        return this.li;
    }
}


var l1 = new listItem(1);
$("ul").append(l1.getDom());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
</ul>
```

See? now the li element is changing.

Comment: That does help! Quick question, is there a particular reason you use 'let'? I'm a bit unfamiliar with the term.

Comment: [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) it's a keyword for scoping of your variables,  you can use `var` because the scope of your variable is local.  Read that link to learn a little more.

Comment: In jQuery, I thought it should be `$("li")` instead of `$("<li>")`?